# Console.ReadLine() from command line input arguments

Tags: c#, input, arguments

is there a way that I can give input arguments from the console into the Console.ReadLine method of C#?

The code I'm working with comes with Console.ReadLine() and I want to test its functionality by providing the .exe file with a few input arguments, that I have predefined.

EDIT:

This is just a sample code, that I want to run:

```
using System;

class AreaRectangle
{
static void Main()
    {
    //Rectangle Area: A (area) = L (length) x W (width)
    decimal lengthSide = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    decimal widthSide = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    decimal area = lengthSide * widthSide;
    Console.WriteLine(area);
    }
}
```

I don't want to ask whoever is giving me code to use

```
    decimal lengthSide = decimal.Parse(args[0]);
    decimal widthSide = decimal.Parse(args[1]);
```

so I was wondering if there's a way for me to execute this from my rpi using the following command

> mono program.exe args0 args1

that being executed from a bash script

Thanks,

Comment: could you share your code, how do you use the `Console.ReadLine` ?

Comment: You could do it with the `<` shell operator and a text file containing the input. Assuming Windows, but Linux/Mac have the same functionality: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Comment: updated my question with a more accurate example

Comment: You could create a shell script that launches your application using the `<` operator but accepts the parameters as you've shown in your example. Short of writing a custom shell, I think that's your only option here.

Comment: @itsme86 works like a charm. Thanks a lot for your help, appreciate it!